# create a commons config Configuration object from standard Properties object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-commons-config

I am loading settings from a YAML file and having Spring autowire the results in a `Properties` bean like so:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myPrefix")
@Bean
private Properties getProperties() {
    return new Properties();
}
```

However, the `Properties` class is rather limiting, and I would like to have an [Apache commons config](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) `Configuration` object. The commons config documentation says that it can be integrated with Spring, but I don't see an example for this simple use case.

How can I autowire an apache commons `Configuration` in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there is any ready-made solution for getting an Apache Commons Configuration object. However, you can get Spring's [`Environment`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) object, which implements [`PropertyResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html), which is much more advanced than `Properties` (you can retrieve properties of any class type). You can get it autowired in your application's constructor like so:

```
...
private final Environment env;
@Autowired
public MyApplication(Environment env) {
    this.environment = env;
}
...
```